# Посчитать количество одинаковых маршрутов и применить в другой функции

Tags: sql, access

Здравсвтуйте, делаю лабораторную и столкнулся с такой задачей:

> Выявление этапов маршрутов с максимальной длинной, маршрут с
>   наибольшим числом туристов, что прошли по нему

Написал, данный код, но как-то не корректно работает.

```
SELECT Max(Етап.Довжина) AS Выражение1
FROM (           Маршрут 
      INNER JOIN Етап ON Маршрут.id = Етап.Маршрут
    ) INNER JOIN Подоріж ON Маршрут.id = Подоріж.Маршрут
WHERE Етап.Маршрут = (SELECT `Подоріж.Маршрут` 
                      FROM `Подоріж` 
                      GROUP BY `Подоріж.Маршрут` 
                      HAVING count(*)>1);
```

Схема БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для получения записи с максимальным значением не нужен подзапрос. Достаточно взять TOP 1 при соотв. сортировке. Правда, сначала надо узнать: если с таким количеством несколько маршрутов, что нужно - все их или только один (любой или отобранный по иному параметру).

Comment: *как-то не корректно работает* Само собой... `HAVING count(*)>1` как-то не очень похоже на критерий максимальности значения...

Comment: И как это сделать? Пример с `HAVING count(*)>1` я брал с интернета, он был в примере к решению задач

Comment: Ну надо же не только взять, но и понять, нафига оно тут... `HAVING count(*)>1` в запросе присутствует для того, чтобы отобрать дубликаты записей. А Вам надо отсортировать по убыванию количества и взять только первую запись.

Comment: Так в Order By можно только по возрастанию или убыванию отсортировать(и вроде еще есть case какой-то)

Comment: *в Order By можно только по возрастанию или убыванию отсортировать ...* Угу... только Вы забыли добавить "... по значению любого поля, выражения или их комбинации".